# Delphi TPopupMenu design modifications

Tags: delphi, vcl, popupmenu, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Can we achieve the below look and feel with TPopupMenu VCl component
[image: Required Design of VCL TPopupMenu]

Can someone guide us in achieving the design?

I have tried setting OwnerDraw to True and wrote the OnDrawItem for menu items, But that is not successfull.

```
procedure TForm.tCopyDrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; Selected: Boolean);
var
  s: string;
begin
  // change font
  ACanvas.Font.Name := 'Noto Sans';
  ACanvas.Font.Size := 12;
  //ACanvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  ACanvas.Font.Color := $00757575;
  // change background
  ACanvas.Brush.Color := clWindow;
  ACanvas.Rectangle(ARect);
  // write caption/text
  s := (Sender as TMenuItem).Caption;
  //ACanvas.TextOut(ARect.Left + 2, ARect.Top + 2 , s);
  ACanvas.TextOut(-2, -2, s);
end;
```

after compiling this I got the look and feel like below.

[image: PopupMenu Design Inprogress]

I have to eliminate that black border and align the items vertically.

**UPDATE**

I have managed to write some code to get the UI as shown in the image but only the Vertical line separator in-between icons and text is missing.
My code is as below:

```
procedure TForm1.pmiProjectCopyDrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas;
  ARect: TRect; Selected: Boolean);
var
  bt: Tbitmap;
begin
  bt := Tbitmap.Create;
  with TMenuItem(Sender) do
  begin
    with ACanvas do
    begin
      Brush.Color := clWhite;
      FillRect(ARect);
      pen.Color := $00E5DFD7;
      if Selected then
      begin
        Font.Color := $006C4E1F;
      end
      else
      begin
         Font.Color := $00757575;
      end;
      Font.Size := 8;
      Font.Name := 'Noto Sans';
      if Caption = '-' then
      begin
        MoveTo(ARect.left + 25, ARect.Top + 3);
        LineTo(ARect.Width, ARect.Top + 3);
      end
      else
      begin
        ImageList1.GetBitmap(ImageIndex, bt);
        Draw(ARect.left + 3, ARect.Top + 3, bt);
        ARect.left := ARect.left + 25;
        DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, PChar(Caption), Length(Caption), ARect,
          DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER);
        DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, PChar(ShortCutToText(shortcut)),
          Length(ShortCutToText(shortcut)), ARect, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_RIGHT);
      end;
    end;

  end;
end;
```

when i compile this code my output is as below : 
[image: PopupMenu]

Only thing left is I want to get a vertical line as shown in below image: 
[image: Vertical line]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the design as specified in this image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI3oO.jpg

Comment: Owner or custom painting menus is really very difficult. Probably your best chance is to use VCL styles.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to write some code to get the UI as shown in the image but only the Vertical line separator in-between icons and text is missing.
My code is as below:

```
procedure TForm1.pmiProjectCopyDrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas;
  ARect: TRect; Selected: Boolean);
var
  bt: Tbitmap;
begin
  bt := Tbitmap.Create;
  with TMenuItem(Sender) do
  begin
    with ACanvas do
    begin
      Brush.Color := clWhite;
      FillRect(ARect);
      pen.Color := $00E5DFD7;
      if Selected then
      begin
        Font.Color := $006C4E1F;
      end
      else
      begin
         Font.Color := $00757575;
      end;
      Font.Size := 8;
      Font.Name := 'Noto Sans';
      if Caption = '-' then
      begin
        MoveTo(ARect.left + 25, ARect.Top + 3);
        LineTo(ARect.Width, ARect.Top + 3);
      end
      else
      begin
        ImageList1.GetBitmap(ImageIndex, bt);
        Draw(ARect.left + 3, ARect.Top + 3, bt);
        ARect.left := ARect.left + 25;
        DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, PChar(Caption), Length(Caption), ARect,
          DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER);
        DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, PChar(ShortCutToText(shortcut)),
          Length(ShortCutToText(shortcut)), ARect, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_RIGHT);
      end;
    end;

  end;
end;
```

when i compile this code my output is as below : 
[image: PopupMenu]

Only thing left is I want to get a vertical line as shown in below image: 
[image: Vertical line]

Comment: Can you add a part of the line to each item image?

Answer (score 0):

> I have to eliminate that black border and align the items vertically.

This is written in C++. I've assumed that the `MenuItem` string is known. 
The `DoGetMenuString` function is not accessible.

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Undo1DrawItem(TObject *Sender, TCanvas *ACanvas,
      TRect &ARect, bool Selected)
{ 
  // The assumptions are that the Canvas colors etc and the Rect sizes 
  // are already set by the program 

  // The text has two spaces at the front and four spaces at the end 

  const AnsiString ItemStr("  Undo              Ctrl+Z    ");

  // calculate the position to draw the text

  static int textpos = (ARect.Height() - ACanvas->TextHeight(ItemStr)) / 2;


  // choose the color for the text

  if( Selected)
    ACanvas->Font->Color = clCream;
  else
    ACanvas->Font->Color = clAqua;


  // Fill the whole rectangle

  ACanvas->FillRect(ARect);


  // write text to Canvas

  ACanvas->TextOut(
    ARect.Left,
    textpos,
    ItemStr);
}
```